# Math error when trying to calculate the distance between two coordinates in python

Tags: python, coordinates, distance, django, haversine

I'm not sure if this is the right place but I am trying to develop a Django site that (among other things) shows public projects within 30 km of a given French commune. It mostly works fine but for some municipalities (for example Marseille) I have an error when trying to display the page, which after investigation seems to be related not to Django or PostgreSQL but to the actual coordinates I have in the database (those coordinates are from a public dataset provided by the French government)

As you can see below, I tried to isolate the problem : it occurs when trying to do the distance calculation for the projects located inside Marseille (line 172). If I change the latitude by a few meters (line 173), it is now able to correctly calculate that the distance is zero:

```
In [166]: paris.longitude
Out[166]: 2.347

In [167]: paris.latitude
Out[167]: 48.8589

In [168]: marseille.longitude = 5.3806

In [169]: marseille.latitude = 43.2803

In [170]: marseille.save()

In [171]: acos(cos(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...:     * cos(radians(paris.latitude))
     ...:     * cos(radians(paris.longitude) - radians(marseille.longitude))
     ...:     + sin(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...:     * sin(radians(paris.latitude))
     ...: ) * 6371
Out[171]: 662.847013493097

In [172]: acos(cos(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...:     * cos(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...:     * cos(radians(marseille.longitude) - radians(marseille.longitude))
     ...:     + sin(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...:     * sin(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...: ) * 6371
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[172], line 1
----> 1 acos(cos(radians(marseille.latitude))
      2    * cos(radians(marseille.latitude))
      3    * cos(radians(marseille.longitude) - radians(marseille.longitude))
      4    + sin(radians(marseille.latitude))
      5    * sin(radians(marseille.latitude))
      6 ) * 6371

ValueError: math domain error

In [173]: marseille.latitude = 43.2804

In [174]: marseille.save()

In [175]: acos(cos(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...:     * cos(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...:     * cos(radians(marseille.longitude) - radians(marseille.longitude))
     ...:     + sin(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...:     * sin(radians(marseille.latitude))
     ...: ) * 6371
Out[175]: 0.0
```

I'm not a mathematician, nor used to manipulate geographic information. What is the cause of the problem? Can the same error occur when calculating the distance between two different cities? Can I fix it without having to manually change the coordinates for an unknown number of the 36000 French municipalities?

Note : it is a simplification of the actual code used, which is here: https://github.com/MTES-MCT/aides-territoires/blob/7742d9f69aa60255e674542b9faa595b61b3ed20/src/projects/forms.py#L441

Comment: you could try breaking the calculation out into separate steps to see which step is failing, or switch to using a geographic library like Shapely to handle the maths for you.

Comment: Alas, I can't, as all of this logic is passed inside an annotation in my Django queryset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after more checks (and a bit of arithmetic), calculating the distance between two identical points should simplify to calculating the arccosine of 1, which is 0.

Due to a float rounding error, and depending on the system, it sometimes tries to calculates the arccosine of something like 0.999997 or 1.000003 instead of 1, which in turn causes a math error if the value is >1.

Fortunately, Django database functions have a way to cap the value, so I solved the issue this way:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import ACos, Cos, Radians, Sin, Round, Least

qs = (
    qs.annotate(
        distance=Round(
            ACos(
                Least(
                    Cos(Radians(search_perimeter.latitude))
                    * Cos(Radians(F("organization__perimeter__latitude")))
                    * Cos(
                        Radians(F("organization__perimeter__longitude"))
                        - Radians(search_perimeter.longitude)
                    )
                    + Sin(Radians(search_perimeter.latitude))
                    * Sin(Radians(F("organization__perimeter__latitude"))),
                    1.0,
                )
            )
            * 6371,
            precision=2,
        )
    )
    .filter(distance__lte=30)
    .order_by("distance")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just running this in python it seems to calculate the distance without error, though the marseille to marseille distance is 0.0013 rather than 0.

```
import numpy
from math import acos, cos, sin, radians

paris = [48.8589, 2.347]

marseille = [43.2803, 5.3806]


p2m = acos(cos(radians(marseille[0]))
     * cos(radians(paris[0]))
     * cos(radians(paris[1]) - radians(marseille[1]))
     + sin(radians(marseille[0]))
     * sin(radians(paris[0]))
     )* 6371
print(p2m)

m2m = acos(cos(radians(marseille[0]))
    * cos(radians(marseille[0]))
    * cos(radians(marseille[1]) - radians(marseille[1]))
    + sin(radians(marseille[0]))
    * sin(radians(marseille[0]))
    ) * 6371
print(m2m)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, because it confirmed the intuition I had after posting the question: it is a float rounding error and depending on the system it tries to calculate the acos of something slightly inferior to 1 (your result) or slightly superior (mine, which results in a math error).